# Groovy - writing and formatting excel 2010

Tags: java, excel, groovy

What are th options for working with an excel workbook from within a groovy (java) environment?  We would like to be able to use the following features

1. add sheets
2. add cells: headings and data
3. format columns, rows, cells

and potentially

1. form pivot tables
2. copy the pivot table by value
3. paste clipboard by value on another screen

Essentially this will allow us to forma  pivot table but remove the underlying data from the worksheet.

Thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try apache poi.  Can definitely perform your first list of requirements.  I have used this api a good bit.  If you have any questions, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Several Java libraries are available to handle the requirements you're looking for:

- [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)
- [OpenOffice API](http://api.openoffice.org)
- [JExcelAPI](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/&ei=fRzdTdrALMqcOovw1PYO&usg=AFQjCNE4n-odRPPG4s9IFjj5osB0uSUhZQ)
- [Jacob](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/)
- ...

Not sure which one can easily handle pivot tables.

Good luck with your project!
Wim

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+for+the+Office) describes some more Groovy-specific options, but my recommendation would be to use Apache POI, either from Java or Groovy